# Variadic Parameter of Class Types - Java

Tags: java, generics

Take for instance, the method below.

```
<T extends MyInterface> void myFunction(Class<T>... types) {
    // Do some stuff that requires T to implement MyInterface
}
```

Now, given the method call below assuming `MyClass1` and `MyClass2` both implement `MyInterface`.

```
myFunction(MyClass1.class, MyClass2.class)
```

I get the following error.

> Incompatible equality constraint: MyClass1 and MyClass2

How do I make this work? More specifically, how would one use a variadic parameter of class types implementing an interface in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've declared `T` to have an upper bound of `MyInterface`.  By passing in `MyClass1.class` and `MyClass2.class`, the compiler must infer `MyInterface` for `T`.

However, the type of the parameter `type` is `Class<T>...`, restricting what is passed in to `MyInterface.class` and no subtypes.

Depending on the "stuff" you're doing, you can place a wildcard upper bound on the type of `types` to get it to compile.

```
<T extends MyInterface> void myFunction(Class<? extends T>... types) {
```

Answer (score 3):

Having a `T` means that `T` has one fixed value, which means that all of the `Class<T>...` parameters must be the exact same type. The compiler cannot infer `T==MyInferface` because `Class<MyClass1>` is not a subclass of `Class<MyInterface>`.

You want to allow each parameter to have a different type. That requires a different signature:

```
void myFunction(Class<? extends MyInterface>... types)
```

There's no need for `T` at all.

Answer (score 1):

With the first parameter, the type variable `T` is set to `MyClass1`.
`MyClass1` should implement the interface, so the constraint `extends MyInterface` is fulfilled.
 Of course a `Class<MyClass2>` is not a `Class<MyClass1>`.

And that's why you get the error.